# Rkhunter doesn't update in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: rkhunter

Everytime I give the command, on terminal, sudo rkhunter --update or sudo rkhunter --versioncheck comes out an error about the wrong directory /bin/false, and doesn't update ?!

Comment: `/bin/false` looks like it'd be a shell thing, not an `rkhunter` thing.  Are you running `rkhunter` yourself as a user, or with `root`, or in its own dedicated user, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug identified in RKHunter where updating could have been compromised. A short term fix by devs (Debian?) was to disable updating via the RKHunter config file. To fix:

Make sure your system is updated and RKHunter is a late version and newer than 1.4.2.6

In a terminal open a text editor as root and navigate to `/etc/rkhunter.conf`, for example;

```
sudo gedit /etc/rkhunter.conf
```

or in Lubuntu

```
sudo leafpad /etc/rkhunter.conf
```

look for the following three items and change these back to defaults as shown here,

```
UPDATE_MIRRORS=1

MIRRORS_MODE=0

WEB_CMD=""
```